# Is there a way to load a jpg image to a UILabel from building the app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to build the app with a jpg image into a UILabel?

(in coding how do I incorporate the file into the build?)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a `UIView` with a `UILabel` plunked on it, possibly with a transparent background, and a `UIImageView`. Depending on how often you change the `label.text` or `imageView.image`, you may want to subclass `UIView` to make this more manageable.

Just add the `myImage.jpg` file to the project in Xcode, and then do

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"];
```